# PyQt application closes immediately after start

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I'm trying make an **exe** application from my scripts using **py2exe**. The problem is that if I run it by doubleclicking on exe file, it closes immediately after open. If I run it from cmd, it works perfect.

I've tried to make a `table` global but it did not helped. I've already tried to keep the reference - no effect.

Here is the code of GUI in case it helps:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem,QApplication
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os
from meteo import mesiac,den

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = data
        self.setmydata()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def setmydata(self):     
        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(['max teplota','min teplota','max vlhkost','min vlhkost','max tlak',
                     'min tlak','avg teplota','avg vlhkost','avg tlak']):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

        vertical_headers = ['{}.'.format(x+1) for x in xrange(len(self.data.values()[0])-1)]+['Mesiac:']
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(vertical_headers)
        self.setWindowTitle('Meteo')

def show_table():
    global table
    table = MyTable(data, len(data.values()[0]), len(data.keys()))
    table.setFixedHeight(len(data.values()[0])*20)
    table.setFixedWidth(len(data.keys())*95)
    table.show()
    return table

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {}
    os.system("mode con: cols=100 lines=40")
    filenames = next(os.walk('mesiac'))[2]
    list_of_den = []
    for filename in filenames:
        list_of_den.append(den(filename,filename[:-4]))
    m = mesiac(list_of_den)

    for den in list_of_den:
        for n,attr in enumerate(['max teplota','min teplota','max vlhkost','min vlhkost','max tlak',
                     'min tlak','avg teplota','avg vlhkost','avg tlak']):
            try:
                data[attr].append(den.to_list()[n])
            except:
                data[attr]=[den.to_list()[n]]

    m_list = m.to_list()
    for n,attr in enumerate(['max teplota','min teplota','max vlhkost','min vlhkost','max tlak',
                     'min tlak','avg teplota','avg vlhkost','avg tlak']):

        try:
            data[attr].append(m_list[n])
        except:
            data[attr]=[m_list[n]]

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = show_table()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And for sure - here is a `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

options ={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip","PyQt4.QtGui","PyQt4.QtCore","meteo"],"dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll", "HID.DLL", "w9xpopen.exe"]}}

setup(window=['table.py'],options=options)
```

How to make it visible?

Comment: My initial guess is that you have a relative path `filenames = next(os.walk('mesiac'))[2]`, which may be valid on the command line, but not when you double click and raises an exception causing it to exit. Try changing it to an absolute path, based upon current app location possible.

Comment: Thank you, now, it works. I had forgotten to copy the folder into 'dist' folder